# [ros2_control] Combined hw_interface for arm and gripper

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a robot that's a little unusual in that the manufacturer combined gripper control and arm joint control into a single, unified API. Thus, we can't really instantiate 2 objects to control gripper and arm separately. We aren't sure how to control the gripper and the arm in a combined fashion.

Our first attempt has a controllers.yaml like this:

```
joint_trajectory_controller:
  type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

# The gripper controller just relays position commands
gripper_controller:
  type: forward_command_controller/ForwardCommandController

joint_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - joint_1
      - joint_2
      - joint_3
      - joint_4
      - joint_5
      - joint_6
      - joint_7

gripper_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - finger_joint
    interface_name: position
```

Our custom interface inherits like this:

```
class OurMultInterfaceHardware : public hardware_interface::BaseInterface<hardware_interface::SystemInterface
```

When launching on hardware, we can see from some print statements that OurMultiInterfaceHardware gets instantiated twice, which will not work with the manufacturer's API. It works fine in simulation.

The important parts from the launch file:

```
robot_controller_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner.py",
    arguments=[robot_controller, gripp, "-c", "/controller_manager"],
)

gripper_controller_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner.py",
    arguments=[gripper_controller, "-c", "/controller_manager"],
)

nodes_to_start = [
    control_node,
    robot_state_publisher_node,
    rviz_node,
    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
    robot_controller_spawner,
    gripper_controller_spawner,
]
```

I think the crux of the question is, does each controller that gets spawned require its own hardware interface?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383824/%5Bros2_control%5D-combined-hw_interface-for-arm-and-gripper/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2021-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2021-08-05**:
In ros 1 you could start multiple controllers with a single controller_manager. `<node name="arm_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" output="screen" args="arm_joint_state_controller arm_controller gripper_controller"/>` but I don't know about ros2 here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, your configuration looks correct, and the launch file is also.

Generally, controllers do not initialize hardware interfaces not they can instantiate it. Hardware is (at current Foxy version) instantiated automatically when controller manager is started. This can be tested by commenting out spawners.

Spawning of controllers is happening independently from hardware. Corresponding interfaces of the controller and hardware must exist and match.

The issue could be that you are “instantiating” ros2_control-macro in URDF twice. Can you check this?

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2021-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that we tried to include a modular ros2_control xacro for the gripper, like this from the gripper xacro:

```
<!-- ros2 control include -->
<xacro:include filename="$(find my_robot_description)/grippers/robotiq_2f_85/urdf/robotiq_my_robot.ros2_control.xacro" />
<xacro:robotiq_my_robot_ros2_control
name="MyRobotGripperInterfaceHardware" prefix="${prefix}"
use_fake_hardware="${use_fake_hardware}"
fake_sensor_commands="${fake_sensor_commands}"
tf_prefix=""
robot_ip="${robot_ip}" />
```

The second ros2_control xacro spawned a second copy of the hardware_interface.

So it seems like there can only be one inclusion of ros2_control xacro "stuff".

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2021-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1